# .exe program crashes when I try to work with a .txt file

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a .txt file. The task is to read temperatures and give out min, max and average values. The txt file is called Temp.txt and it looks like this :

```
5 76 56 34 35 10
4 45 23 24 14
0
2 32 34
```

Here is the code that I've written. I have also tried to run it using just the file name like 'fopen("Temp.txt","r")' but I get the same result.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int ReadTempFile(FILE *fp, float temperatur[]);
float maxTemp(int anzahl, float temperatur[]);
float minTemp(int anzahl, float temperatur[]);
float mittlereTemp(int anzahl, float temperatur[]);
float fahrenheit(float celsius);

int ReadTempFile(FILE *fp, float temperatur[])    //For reading individual rows from txt file
{
    int i=0;
    fscanf(fp,"%f", &temperatur[0]);
    for(i = 0; i < temperatur[0]; ++i)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%f", &temperatur[i+1]);
    }
    return temperatur[0];
}

float maxTemp(int anzahl, float temperatur[])    //Maximum Temperature
{
    int i = 0;
    float max;
    max = temperatur[i+1];
    for(i = 1; i < anzahl; i++)
    {
        if(temperatur[i+1] > max)
        {
            max = temperatur[i+1];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

float minTemp(int anzahl, float temperatur[])    //Minimum Temperature
{
    int i = 0;
    float min;
    min = temperatur[i+1];
    for(i = 1; i < anzahl; i++)
    {
        if(temperatur[i+1] < min)
        {
            min = temperatur[i+1];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

float mittlereTemp(int anzahl, float temperatur[])    //Average Temperature
{
    int i, sum = 0;
    float mit;
    for (i = 0; i <= anzahl; i++)
    {
        sum += temperatur[i];
    }
    mit = sum/temperatur[0];
    return mit;
}

float fahrenheit(float celsius)    //Celsius to Fahrenheit
{
    float f;
    f = (celsius*9/5) + 32;
    return f;
}


int main()
{
    int end, n, Zeile=1;
    float temperatur[20], max, min, mit, fmax, fmin, fmit;
    char eingabe[20];
    FILE *fp=NULL;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter File name: \n");    //Enter file name
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%s", eingabe);
        fp = fopen(eingabe, "r" );
        if(fp == NULL) printf ("Error: File %s can't be opened!\n", eingabe);    //Error message for File cant be opened
    }while(fp != NULL);

    do{
        n = ReadTempFile(fp, temperatur);

        max = maxTemp(n, temperatur);
        printf("Das Maximum der Zeile %d ist: %.3fC \t",Zeile, max);

        fmax = fahrenheit(max);
        printf("In Fahrenheit: %.3fF\n", fmax);

        min = minTemp(n, temperatur);
        printf("Das Minimum der Zeile %d ist: %.3fC \t",Zeile, min);

        fmin = fahrenheit(min);
        printf("In Fahrenheit: %.3fF\n", fmin);

        mit = mittlereTemp(n, temperatur);
        printf("Der Mittelwert der Zeile %d ist: %.3fC \t",Zeile, mit);

        fmit = fahrenheit(mit);
        printf("In Fahrenheit: %.3fF\n", fmit);

        ++Zeile;

        end = feof(fp);
        printf("\n\n");
    }while (end == 0);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

[This is what happens after I run the above program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjsw9.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn to debug your own code. Run it in a debugger. It will instantly give you the exact line of code that triggers the crash. Can then also use it to trace the program execution to help find where things first start going wrong.

Comment: `while(fp != NULL)` seems wrong

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < temperatur[0]; ++i)` Why is the termination condition `i < temperatur[0]`? Shouldn't it be bounded by the max number of allowed entries in the array?

Comment: If you write `do { ... } while (fp != NULL)`, the program will only proceed to the next instruction after the do-while-loop if `fp == NULL`. I think, you want `while (fp == NULL)`.

Comment: first element of each line should be read and used as an int. conversion to float and back is unnecessary.

Comment: side note: `//Enter file name` is not a useful comment. Comments should not repeat what the program does. They should explain why it is doing it.

Comment: `Error: File %s can't be opened!` sure looks like an error message.  As such, it belongs on stderr.  It is also useful if you inform the user the reason for the failure.  Use either `perror(eingabe);` or `fprintf(stderr, "Error: File %s can't be opened: %s\n", eingabe, strerror(errno));`

Comment: Your incorrect usage of `feof` is somewhat novel, but it is still incorrect.  If there is a read error on the file, `feof` will return 0 and you are stuck in an infinite loop.  You should either use the standard idiom (eg, check the value returned by the read) or at the very least check both `feof` and `ferror`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong

Comment: You neither need nor want to store all the values.  Read through the file and keep a count of the number of items read, the current sum, the min, and the max.

Comment: And don't bother with file I/O.  Read from stdin and write to stdout.  Handle file redirection in the shell.

Comment: ReadTempFile() has a return type of int but you are returning a float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most immediate problem that is likely causing the crash is the logic for opening a file:

```c
do
{
    printf("Enter File name: \n");    //Enter file name
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s", eingabe);
    fp = fopen(eingabe, "r" );
    if(fp == NULL) printf ("Error: File %s can't be opened!\n", eingabe);
}while(fp != NULL);   // <- Loops until it fails
```

This will guarantee that the loop will not end until a file **fails** to open. When you later try to `fscanf` from `fp` set to `NULL`, you'll have *undefined behavior* (and this may manifest itself as a crash).

Suggested fix:

```c
for(;;) {
    puts("Enter File name:");
    if(scanf("%19s", eingabe) == 1) { // make sure scanf succeeds
        fp = fopen(eingabe, "r" );
        if(fp) break;                 // break out when it succeeds to open
        perror(eingabe);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: No filename entered.\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Note: In your example-run, you showed that you entered `Temp` to open `Temp.txt`. You must enter `Temp.txt` to successfully open `Temp.txt`.

---

Here is your program with some other fixes too. I've commented inline so you see why I suggest the changes.

Notes:

- I've removed the `+1` offset in `temperatur` completely. You shouldn't use the first `float` to store the count of temperatures which is an integer value.
- Your `mittlereTemp` didn't use this offset, so it gave the wrong answers too.
- `mittlereTemp` didn't calculate the median temperature (which I think *"mittlereTemp"* means). It tried to calculate the average temperature, so I changed the name to `durchschnittsTemp`.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// For reading individual rows from txt file
// max_anzahl added to not try to read too many
int ReadTempFile(FILE* fp, float temperatur[], int max_anzahl) {
    int count;
    // return -1 on failure
    if(fscanf(fp, "%d", &count) != 1) return -1;

    // we can't read all the entries if count > max_anzahl
    if(count > max_anzahl || count < 0) return -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if(fscanf(fp, "%f", &temperatur[i]) != 1) {
            return -1; // could not read count floats, failure
        }
    }

    return count;
}

// The idiomatic way is to have the array pointer first and
// the count second so I swapped the order of temperatur and anzahl:
float maxTemp(float temperatur[], int anzahl) {
    if(anzahl == 0) return NAN; // if we have no values, we have no max temp

    float max = temperatur[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < anzahl; i++) {
        if(temperatur[i] > max) {
            max = temperatur[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

float minTemp(float temperatur[], int anzahl) {
    if(anzahl == 0) return NAN; // if we have no values, we have no min temp

    float min = temperatur[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < anzahl; i++) {
        if(temperatur[i] < min) {
            min = temperatur[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

// I changed the name to durchschnittsTemp
float durchschnittsTemp(float temperatur[], int anzahl) {
    if(anzahl == 0) return NAN; // if we have no values, we have no average temp

    float sum = 0.f;            // use the proper type for sum

    for(int i = 0; i < anzahl; i++) {
        sum += temperatur[i];
    }
    return sum / (float)anzahl;
}

float fahrenheit(float celsius) {
    float f;
    f = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;
    return f;
}

// since opening the file is a lot of code, make a function
FILE* open_file_supplied_by_the_user() {
    char eingabe[FILENAME_MAX]; // make plenty of room for the filename
    for(;;) {
        puts("Enter File name:");
        // use fgets instead of scanf to make it easier to read filenames with spaces
        if(fgets(eingabe, sizeof eingabe, stdin)) {
            size_t len = strlen(eingabe);
            eingabe[len - 1] = '\0';
            FILE* fp = fopen(eingabe, "r");
            if(fp) return fp; // break out when it succeeds to open
            perror(eingabe);  // give the user a proper error message
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: No filename entered.\n");
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}

#define Size(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof *(x))

int main() {
    FILE* fp = open_file_supplied_by_the_user();
    if(fp == NULL) return 1; // exit if no file was opened

    float temperatur[20];

    // loop until ReadTempFile() returns -1 (failure)
    for(int n, Zeile = 1;
        (n = ReadTempFile(fp, temperatur, Size(temperatur))) != -1;
        ++Zeile)
    {
        float max = maxTemp(temperatur, n);
        printf("Das Maximum der Zeile %d ist: %.3fC \t", Zeile, max);
        printf("In Fahrenheit: %.3fF\n", fahrenheit(max));

        float min = minTemp(temperatur, n);
        printf("Das Minimum der Zeile %d ist: %.3fC \t", Zeile, min);
        printf("In Fahrenheit: %.3fF\n", fahrenheit(min));

        float mit = durchschnittsTemp(temperatur, n);
        printf("Der Durchschnittswert der Zeile %d ist: %.3fC \t", Zeile, mit);
        printf("In Fahrenheit: %.3fF\n", fahrenheit(mit));

        printf("\n\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback Ted. I tried running the code with your suggested fix. It continues in an endless loop with every value as 0. What could be the reason?

Comment: @Hilfe You're welcome! With only the above changes, the program successfully read the file and presented some values and then exited cleanly for me. It printed some `-nan`s though.

Comment: Did it give proper calculated values for the respective temp values? My program isn't exiting at all. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: @Hilfe The only thing I did was to take the program in the question and change the part I showed and then it worked and all by the `0` line looked ok. I've added a version of your program with some suggested changes.

Comment: That's absolutely amazing! I am utterly grateful to you Ted! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Hilfe You're welcome. if you actually need the _median_ value too, you can `qsort` `temperatur` like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/veeW8G9en) and just pick the middle value (or two two middle values if there's an even amount of temperatures). Note that you then get `min` and `max` "for free" since those will be the first and last values in the array.